# How to config dolphin UI and get rid of alternated colored rows?

Tags: linux, user-interface, kde-plasma, manjaro

I just installed two identical systems of Manjaro/KDE/Plasma 6.1 from the same USB, one laptop and one desktop.  In sys #1, dolphin looks lovely, but in #2, it has those insanely annoying black and white colored bars, making it genuinely stressful and unpleasant to look at, let alone read, but the latter is academic as the black fonts in the black stripes make it impossible to read.

To make sure I have the same configs in both systems, I used "konsave" to copy my KDE/Plasma config from #1 to #2, and I made sure the setting QT settings were identical, but the lines remained.

If it's not KDE, Plasma, or QT setting, where are they?  How can I get rid of these obnoxious black and white lines?

I have purged dolphin (pacman -Rns dolphin) and tried both dolphin and dolphin-git (because for some odd reason, sys#2 installed dolphin-git and sys#1 installed dolphin).

FYI: I can get rid of the black lines with the following CSS in ".config/dolphin.qss"

```
DolphinViewContainer > DolphinView > QAbstractScrollArea {
      background-color: transparent;
}
```

and starting dolphin with

```
dolphin --stylesheet ~/.config/dolphin.qss
```

However, that also generates the error:

```
QObject::disconnect: Unexpected nullptr parameter
Could not parse application stylesheet
kf.coreaddons: Expected a KPluginFactory, got a KIOPluginForMetaData
kf.coreaddons: Expected a KPluginFactory, got a KIOPluginForMetaData
kf.coreaddons: Expected a KPluginFactory, got a KIOPluginForMetaData
```

But is does something good, nevertheless.

The qt5ct config stylesheets do absolutely nothing :/

Answer (score 0):

Dolphin may be reading configuration information defining appearance from the `~/.config/kdeglobals` file.

Kill Dolphin, edit the `kdeglobals` file and try changing the `BackgroundNormal` value, and then reopen Dolphin to see if this is the case.

For example, the change below removes the "striping" pattern on my system:

```
[Colors:Button]
BackgroundAlternate=64,69,82
BackgroundNormal=60,68,84
```

to

```
[Colors:View]
BackgroundAlternate=64,69,82
BackgroundNormal=#FFFFFF
```